# jsdom: Appending scripts to body with jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, dom, jsdom

How do you append a script to the DOM body using jsdom and jQuery? The obvious answer of using `$('body').append('<script src="..."></script>')` actually ends up adding the script in the document `head`.

This is the basic node.js script I'm testing with:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env(
    "http://google.com",
    ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js'],
    function(err, window) {
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        $('body').append('<script src="http://example.com/script.js"></script>');
        console.log($('html').html());
    }
);
```

which results in something beginning with:

```
<head><script src="http://example.com/script.js?_=1352426933034"></script>...
```

Interestingly, if you add a space in `<sc ript src="..."></script>` this is appended correctly, so something (jsdom, I expect) is hijacking this script so it can add the cachebuster(?) and place it in the header. What's causing this and **how do I prevent it from happening** so it appends the script instead?

For what its worth,

```
$ npm ls
/Users/codyaray/dev/proxy/test
└─┬ jsdom@0.2.19
  ├─┬ contextify@0.1.3
  │ └── bindings@1.0.0
  ├── cssom@0.2.5
  ├── cssstyle@0.2.3
  ├── htmlparser@1.7.6
  └─┬ request@2.11.4
    ├─┬ form-data@0.0.3
    │ ├── async@0.1.9
    │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.3
    │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
    └── mime@1.2.7
```

Comment: Not an answer but you can try using [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio)

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue with jsdom, only I want to append the `<script>` to `<head>`.

Following code:

```
$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>');
```

resulted in this:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js?_=1352426933034"></script>
</head>
```

This seems to be only happening when appending `<script>` element with `src` attribute already set. All seems to be all right when you first append empty `<script>` and **then** set its `src` like this:

```
$('<script>').appendTo($('head')).attr('src','script.js');
```